# Como criar um projeto angular sem Initial commit?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Como não há exemplo na documentação do angular.io, não consigo iniciar um projeto sem que ele execute um Initial commit, conforme opções da documentação, tentei de diversas formas e nada, sempre cria!

```
--commit=true|false                 

Initial git repository commit information.

Default: true
```

Comment: Curiosidade: por que é um problema ter esse commit inicial? Já tentou excluir a pasta do Git e criar o repositório novamente?

Comment: Então, é porque gosto de usar o Git Flow, por isso gostaria de iniciar com ele.

Comment: Eu vi que posso excluir o .git, mas como há a opção na documentação, gostaria que funcionasse, até porque qualquer projeto que fizesse teria que excluir o .git sempre!

Answer (score 0):

Para não executar o commmit inicial é só adicionar ao comando o atributo '--commit=false'

```
ng new <nome-app> --commit=false
```

Ele irá criar o repositório, porém não irá efetuar nenhum commit. Pode verificar isso ao entrar na pasta do projeto e usar o comando 'git log' e ele irá acusar um erro '**fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet**'

Está bem descrito na documentação do [angular.io](https://angular.io/cli/new)

Mas caso não queria utilizar o git no projeto, aí é só apagar a pasta '.git' que fica dentro do diretório do projeto. Porém, não recomendo apagar a pasta do git e deixaria também o commit inicial sendo executado, já que não interfere em nada no fluxo de trabalho.

Comment: Então Maikon, como eu disse antes eu tentei de todas as formas, inclusive dessa forma que você colocou da um erro dizendo que eu tenho que seguir o padrão em JSON, daí fiz em {"commit": "false", "style": "scss", etc.} e executou, mas o commit continua sendo feito!

Comment: Eu executei tudo do 0, instalei o @angular/cli, depois executei o comando ng new <nome> --commit=false e ele criou o projeto sem efetuar o primeiro commit, somente adicionando os arquivos a árvore. Também executei a criação de outro projeto usando o padrão do angular e ele efetuou o commit. 

Verifica os passos da criação do seu projeto novamente, por que seguindo a documentação o comando funciona.

A primeiro commit não interfere em nada no seu fluxo de trabalho, ao meu ver, não tem necessidade de adicionar o comando --commit=false mesmo usando Git Flow.